# Can't populate my OLEObject combobox

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to populate my combobox through an adodb connection and recordset with data from an access database. The code has previously run fine but in a normal userform, my issue is that I can't properly reference to the combobox.additem property.

How do I reference to it when the ActiveX object is directly on the worksheet "Mainwindow"? 
The codename of the shape is: CombBox_Instruments
The control code name should be: Forms.ComboBox.1

I have market where I get the error, the current error is: Run time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
  Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

  Dim SQLString As String
  Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

  DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
  DataConnection.Open

  SQLString = "SELECT Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type =1 AND Flags=0"

  With RecordSet
    .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
    .Source = SQLString
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
    End With

Do Until RecordSet.EOF = True
    If RecordSet.Fields(0) <> "Instruments" Then
        Debug.Print RecordSet.Fields(0)
        Sheets("Mainwindow").OLEObjects("Forms.ComboBox.1").AddItem RecordSet.Fields(0) - ISSUE IS HERE!
        RecordSet.MoveNext
    Else
        RecordSet.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Combo Box named `CombBox_Instruments` is on the sheet "Mainwindow" your code should be:

```
Sheets("Mainwindow").CombBox_Instruments.AddItem RecordSet.Fields(0)
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Strange thing is, I tried that but with .value and it couldn't find the property. Still when I use it in my if statement in an additional event handler the .value property clearly works for the combbox_instruments. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: For example here: If CombBox_Instruments.Value <> "" And DTPicker_FROM.Value < DTPicker_TO.Value Then
        Call ChartBuilder.Create(TickerID, DTPicker_FROM.Value, DTPicker_TO.Value)
    End If